# Get Dataset returned from an ajax enabled wcf service

Tags: ajax, dataset, wcf

I call an ajax enabled wcf service method ,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetEmployee() {
        Service.GetEmployeeData('1','5',onGetDataSuccess);
    }
    function onGetDataSuccess(result) {
        Iteratejsondata(result)
            }
     </script>
```

and my method is ,

```
[OperationContract]
public string GetEmployeeData(int currentPage,int pageSize)
{
    DataSet ds = GetEmployeeViewData(currentPage,pageSize);
    return GetJSONString(ds.Tables[0]);
}
```

My `Dataset ds` contains three datatable but i am using the first one for my records...
Other two datatables have values how can i get them in `result`...

```
function onGetDataSuccess(result) {
        Iteratejsondata(result)
            }
```

Any suggestion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only suggestion: **do not use DataSets over WCF!**

DataSets are evil - they're huge, they carry lots of overhead, the mix data with behavior - all things you should try to avoid like the plague when doing proper SOA. This is doubly true when you're doing Ajax calls asynchronously - you want to transfer as little data as possible using JSON - and having a DataSet with DataTables does not help you at all for your JSON calls...

So really : get yourself acquainted with some kind of an ORM, and grab objects and lists of objects and toss the DataSets onto the digital recycling heap.....

For a small project, if you're using SQL Server as your backend, why not use Linq-to-SQL? Or if that doesn't work for you, check out [Subsonic](http://www.subsonicproject.com/)

Comment: @marc_s since its a small application what orm can i use?

Comment: you could try Linq-to-SQL if you have SQL Server, or something like Subsonic.